# Find the inserted element in the list

Tags: algorithm

In a recent interview I was asked:

If you have 2 lists

listA
listB

Each are the size 1000 and contain the same elements 1 - 1000. If an element, N is added to listB how can you determine the value of that element?

I responded correctly by saying to subtract listB from listA and the remainder would be the value.

Then he said what if we just have listB after N was added. How would you determine the value that was added?

I failed to answer this!!!! I should know it but I just cant think of it. The hint he gave was to do something similar as I did in the first problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are the elements {1,2,3 .... 1000}?

Comment: "size 1000 and contain the same elements 1 - 1000": does this mean that each list contains each value between 1 and 1000 exactly once, or does it mean that each list contains 1000 elements, each element is in the range 1 - 1000, the two lists contain the same elements (perhaps not in the same order), but there may be dupes? If the latter then without having listA, or a chance to see listB before N is added, then clearly it's not possible to know which element was added to listB last. If the former then the problem's simple, e.g. just subtract 500500 from the sum of elements of listB.

Comment: http://betterexplained.com/articles/techniques-for-adding-the-numbers-1-to-100/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclusive XOR both lists and whatever is new (N) you will have it. This is the answer to the first question.

Comment: Yeah that is a good idea and much better than adding both and subtracting from each other.

Answer (score 2):

Sum `A` into `sumA`. Insert a new element. Sum the list now into `sumB`. Subtract `sumA` from `sumB`. Viola is a musical instrument.

Comment: I know the first one, but I dont know the second. I only have listB now.

Comment: I understood the question that you don't keep `listA` and `listB` to diff. But you have to remember *something*, otherwise it's impossible. So sum the `listA` *before* you add the element, remember the sum, then sum the `listB` after you add the element. Also, what @SteveJessop said - you should know by the question format what the sum of `listA` is.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the list is not automatically sorted when inserting new elements, you can determine what the new element is if you know what the list's "Add" method implementation is.

If the list adds the new element by appending it, you know the new element will be the last element in the list.

If the list adds the new element by pre-pending it, you know the new element will be the first element in the list.

If you insert the element into the list, you know exactly where the element is because you specified the location.

If the list randomly inserts the element upon adding it, then you're out of luck. In this case you'll have to have something to use as a comparison (the original list).

This is the result of an object not just having *state*, but also having *behaviour*.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that most of what I do is SQL based:

```
select * 
from listb b
left outer join lista a on (a.id = b.id)
where (a.id is null)
```